# A simple Hello World setuptools package and installing it with pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, pypi

I'm having trouble figuring out how to install my package using setuptools, and I've tried reading the documentation on it and SO posts, but I can't get it to work properly. I'm trying to get a simple helloworld application to work. This is how far I got:

helloworld.py:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

README.txt:

```
Hello, World! readme
```

MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include images *.gif
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='helloworld',
    version='0.1',
    license='BSD',
    author='gyeh',
    author_email='hello@world.com',
    url='http://www.hello.com',
    long_description="README.txt",
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts = ['helloworld.py'],
    package_data={
        "" : ["images/*.gif"]
    },
    data_files=[('images', ['images/hello.gif'])],
    description="Hello World testing setuptools",
)
```

And I have a blank file called images/hello.gif that I want to include in my package as additional data. The folder structure looks like this:

```
testsetup/  
|-- helloworld.py  
|-- images/  
|-- --- hello.gif  
|-- MANIFEST.in  
|-- README.txt  
|-- setup.py
```

When I run `python setup.py sdist`, it generates the `dist` and `helloworld.egg-info` successfully. When I look at SOURCES.txt under egg-info, it contains the script and the image under the images folder, and the tarball under dist contains them as well.

However, when I try to run `pip install --user helloworld-0.1.tar.gz` on the tarball, it successfully installs it, but I can't find the program files helloworld.py and images/hello.gif.

When I look under `$HOME/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/`, I see the egg-info folder and all of it's contents installed there. But the `$HOME/.local/bin` folder doesn't even exist. Are the program files stores elsewhere? What am I doing wrong here? I'm running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 22):

Okay, so after some effort, I finally managed to get a simple **"hello world"** example working for setuptools. The Python documentation is usually amazing, but I wish the documentation was better on this in particular.

I'm going to write a fairly detailed guide on how I achieved this, and I'll assume no prior background on the reader on this topic. I hope this comes in handy for others...

In order to get this example set up, we'll be creating a package (actually two of them, one for the data files). This is the directory structure we'll end up with:

```
test-setuptools/
|-- helloworld/
|-- --- hello.py
|-- --- images/
|-- --- --- hello.gif
|-- --- --- __init__.py
|-- --- __init__.py
|-- MANIFEST.in
|-- README.txt
|-- setup.py
```

Here are the steps:

1. Create the `helloworld` package.
   1.1 Create the `helloworld/` folder as shown in the directory structure above.

   1.2 Add a blank file called `__init__.py` in the `helloworld/` folder.
   If you don't add it, the package won't be recognized (run `touch __init__.py` to create the file on linux/mac machines). If you want some code to be executed every time the package is imported, include it in the `__init__.py` file.

   1.3 Create the the `hello.py` script file to demonstrate the package functionality.

Here is the code for `hello.py`:

```
import os

"""
Open additional data files using the absolute path,
otherwise it doesn't always find the file.
"""
# The absolute path of the directoy for this file:
_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Hello(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        return "Hello, World!"
    def open_image(self):
        print("Reading image.gif contents:")

        # Get the absolute path of the image's relative path:
        absolute_image_path = os.path.join(_ROOT, 'images/hello.gif')

        with open(absolute_image_path, "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line)
```

1. 1.4 Create the `images/` folder inside the `helloworld/` folder.
   Make another blank `__init__.py` file, because this folder will also be a package.

   1.5 Create the `hello.gif` file inside the `images/` folder.
   This file won't be an actual gif file. Instead, add plain text just to demonstrate that non-script files can be added and read.

I added the following code in `hello.gif`:

```
This should be the data inside hello.gif...
...but this is just to demonstrate setuptools,
so it's a dummy gif containing plain text
```

1. 1.6 Test your package
   Run `python` from the `test-setuptools` folder, which will open the python interpreter.
   Type `import helloworld.hello` to import the `hello.py` script in the `helloworld` package. The import should be successful, indicating that you successfully created a package. Make sure that the package in the `images/` folder also works, by typing `import helloworld.images`
   Try instantiating the object that we wrote in `hello.py`. Type the following commands to make sure everything works as expected:
   `hey = helloworld.hello.Hello()`
   `hey.say_hello()`
   `hey.open_image()`
2. Create the `setup.py` file and the remaining files.
   2.1 Create a simple `README.txt` file. Mine just has the text: `Hello, World! Readme` inside.

   2.2 Create a `MANIFEST.in` file with the following contents:
   `include helloworld/images/hello.gif`
   .
   This is very **important** because it tells setuptools to include the additional data in the source distribution (which we'll generate in a later step). Without this, you won't be able to install additional, non `.py` data to your package. See [this](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) for additional details and commands.

   2.3 Create the `setup.py` file (see the code below).
   The most important attributes are `packages`, `include_package_data`, and `package_data`.
   .
   The `packages` attribute contains a list of the packages you want to include for setuptools. We want to include both the `helloworld` package and the `helloworld.images` package that contains our additional data `hello.gif`.
   You can make setuptools automatically find these by adding the `from setuptools import find_packages` import and running the imported `find_packages()` function. Run the interpreter from the `test-setuptools` folder and test this command to see which packages are found.
   .
   The `package_data` attribute tells setuptools to include additional data. It's this command, the `helloworld.images` package, and the `MANIFEST.in` file which allow you to install additional data.
   The `'helloworld.images' : ['hello.gif']` key/value pair tells setuptools to include `hello.gif` inside the `helloworld.images` package if it exists. You can also say `'' : ['*.gif']` to include any .gif file in any of the included packages.
   The `include_package_data` attribute set to `True` is also necessary for this to work.
   You can include additional metadata for the package like I have (I think an `author` is necessary). It's a good idea to add classifiers. Additional info can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html).

Here is the entire `setup.py` code:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='helloworld',
    version='0.1',
    license='BSD',
    author='gyeh',
    author_email='hello@world.com',
    url='http://www.hello.com',
    long_description="README.txt",
    packages=['helloworld', 'helloworld.images'],
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={'helloworld.images' : ['hello.gif']},
    description="Hello World testing setuptools",
)
```

.
3.  Install and test your package with setuptools.

```
3.1 Create the source distribution
```

Run `python setup.py sdist` from the `test-setuptools/` folder to generate the source distribution.
This will create a `dist/` folder containing your package, and a `helloworld.egg-info/` folder containing metadata such as `SOURCE.txt`.
Check `SOURCE.txt` to see if your the `hello.gif` image file is included there.
Open the `.tar.gz` file under the `dist/` folder. You should see all of the files described in the directory structure we made earlier, including `hello.gif` and `hello.py`.

```
3.2 Install the distribution
```

Install the .tar.gz distribution file by running `pip install --user helloworld-0.1.tar.gz` from the `dist/` folder.
Check that the package was successfully installed by running `pip list`. The package `helloworld` should be there.

That's it! now you should be able to test your package under any folder. Open up the interpreter in any folder except `test-setuptools`, and try importing the package using `import helloworld.hello`. It should work. Then try the commands to instantiate the object and open the image file using the `hey.open_image()` command again. It should still work!

You can view exactly which files were installed by pip, and where they are, by uninstalling the package.
Mine looked like this:

```
[gyeh@gyeh package]$ pip uninstall helloworld
Uninstalling helloworld:
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld-0.1-py3.3.egg-info
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/__init__.py
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyc
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/__pycache__/hello.cpython-33.pyc
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/hello.py
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/images/__init__.py
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/images/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-33.pyc
  /home/gyeh/.local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/helloworld/images/hello.gif
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled helloworld
```

As you can see, it successfully installed the additional data file `hello.gif`, and because we converted the relative path to an absolute path in `hello.py`, it can read the file just fine.
You can then share this package on PyPI for the rest of the world to use! The instructions on uploading to PyPI are fairly straightforward and can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/3.1/distutils/uploading.html).

Once it's online in PyPI, people can search for your package using `pip search`. Or alternatively, running `pip install --user [package-name]` will tell pip to search the online PyPI directory for that package name. If it exists, it will install it.

You can run that command for any python package that in PyPI for an easy install so you aren't mucking around with build files.

I hope this saves people a bunch of headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your example should be part of the official docs!! I also got my package working. Thanks again!

Comment: This is the official guides to newbies

Comment: If anyone gets a `Failed building wheel for helloworld`, you probably need to `pip install wheel` first.