# How to supply user functions/modules in DSX

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, ibm-cloud, dsx, data-science-experience

I have some helper utilities defined in a separate python script.  I would like to make the script available to the DSX notebook, so I can call them in the cell, but I don't want to put the script into the cell directly.

What are some of the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with making your code publicly available on a public git repository, you could turn your code into a python package and save it in github.  See here for an example package: [A simple Hello World setuptools package and installing it with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051360/a-simple-hello-world-setuptools-package-and-installing-it-with-pip).

You can install it directly from github using:

```
!pip install --user git+https://github.com/public_account/public_repo
```

### Private github repositories

It should also be possible to use a similar approach as above with a private github repository, with a few extra setup steps and a different url format for pip.  E.g.

Generate a ssh key on dsx

```
! ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
```

Add the output from the following command to your github account settings :: SSH and GPG keys

```
! cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Next add the github ssh key to dsx:

```
! ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

**IMPORTANT:** You should manually verify that the imported github hosts key is authentic.  You can view the imported key with:

```
! cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You can now install with pip:

```
! pip install --user git+ssh://git@github.com/private_account/private_repo
```

**CAUTION!** that there are some security considerations with the above approach.  I.e. anyone with access to the spark service where you performed the above commands will be able to access the git private repository.

---

**NOTE:**

Ideally, In the future, I would like to see dsx provide support for editing all files in a project and committing all the project files to github, e.g.

- https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/suggestions/17836447-provide-much-more-git-functionality
- https://datascix.uservoice.com/forums/387207-general/suggestions/17523673-update-notebooks-to-jupyter-labs-for-full-ide-inte

Comment: If the package is in a folder within the git repo:
!pip install --user "git+https://github.com/user/repo.git#egg=pkgname&subdirectory=folder/to/package"

Comment: It's not necessary to make the code publicly available. Users can upload the package to the file system and then use `pip` on the local file. https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index-gentopic4.html#spark_environment_example

Comment: Thanks Roland - I've added the steps as a separate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41890895/1033422.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to upload your package to your spark account from a client machine using the following API call:

```
curl \
   -X PUT \
   -k \
   -u ${tenant_id}:${tenant_secret} \
   -H "X-Spark-service-instance-id: ${instance_id}" \
   --data-binary "@path_to_local_file" \
   ${cluster_master_url}/tenant/data/destination_file_name
```

The variables above can be obtained by logging in to the Bluemix console and navigating to Service Credentials.  Alternative, you can use the command line `cf` tools to retrieve this information.  This [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098568/how-to-get-vcap-services-environment-variables-without-binding-to-an-application) provides some more information on the `cf` command line approach.

After uploading your package to the spark service, you can use:

```
! pip install --user ${HOME}/data/destination_file_name
```

Credit to [Roland Weber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5629418/roland-weber) for this answer.